# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'publish'

Tags: meteor

I've got console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'publish'
```

There is a line in my server/server.js
(console says that the error is here)

```
Meteor.publish("votes");
```

p.s. In model.js there is this line:

```
Votes = new Meteor.Collection("votes");
```

and in client/client.js there is

```
Meteor.subscribe("votes");
```

(it does not swear on the client part)
Thanks:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor How to export Meteor.publish and Meteor.method code from within a Meteor package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986141/meteor-how-to-export-meteor-publish-and-meteor-method-code-from-within-a-meteor)

Comment: Same error message but looks like different issue.

Comment: @emgee despite the error it works ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is - "meteor update" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this was asked, but since I just ran across and figured out the same problem ...

I suspect you have your `Meteor.publish("votes");` call in a file that's shared between client and server, meaning it executes in both contexts.

The client representation of the `Meteor` class doesn't support `publish`, only the server.

If you move this call into a server-only file (such as in `<project_name>/server`) or inside a server execution context like below, the error should go away.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("votes", {
        return Votes.find(); // or whatever you like
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your publish function should contain an actual function of what to publish.

From the docs:

> To publish records to clients, call Meteor.publish on the server with
>   two parameters: the name of the record set, and a publish function
>   that Meteor will call each time a client subscribes to the name.

So the function should look like:

```
Meteor.publish("votes", function () {
  return Votes.find();
});
```

That may or may not be the problem you're running into here, but is the first problem I see.